# Why doesn't the second verb agree with the subject of that verb in "we watched Obama speak"?

Tags: verbs, bare-infinitive

In 
"We watched Obama speak," what is the technical reason for it not being
"We watched Obama spoke"?

Comment: If you want "spoke" you can say *We watched as Obama spoke*.

Answer (score 8):

The second verb here is the bare infinitive.

A participle could also be used, i.e we watched Obama speaking. The difference in meaning would be aspectual. The first implies that his speaking was a single event (which was watched in full) The second implies that it was a process (which may or may not have been watched in full).

Answer (score 6):

The technical reason is that the object complement clause of *We watched*, viz.

> *(for) Obama (to) speak*

is an **Infinitive** [object complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html) and, since infinitives are tenseless, it can't take a past tense form like *spoke*.  [Sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) like *see, watch, listen,* etc. often use [infinitive complements](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/114389/15299) without the infinitive complementizer *to*.