# Non-finite clause complementation of complex transitive verbs

Tags: grammar, clauses, sense-verbs, bare-infinitive, nonfinite-clause-complementation

This question has been bothering me for a while. It came up when I was reading Chapter 16 of "A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language."

How to explain the grammatical structure of the following four sentences?

"We knew him **to be a spy**."
"I saw her **leave the room**."
"I heard someone **shouting**."
"I got the watch **repaired**."

What category do the four non-finite clauses in boldface fall into? They do not seem to fall into any of relative, nominal, comparative and adverbial clauses.

Answer (score 17):

Quirk et al is a good grammar but weak, I think, on complex sentences.
What we're looking at in all of these examples is the remains of deceased clauses.

Of the four sentences, two:

- *I saw her leave the room*
- *I heard someone shouting*

are examples of special constructions that are limited to [sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), one with an infinitive and the other with a [gerund](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/gerund.html). Note that you can swap infinitive and gerund here, with no particular difference in meaning:

- *I saw her leaving the room*
- *I heard someone shout*

All of these sentences have two meaningful verbs: *see* + *leave* and *hear* + *shout*. That means there are two clauses; [every non-auxiliary verb is a clause](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Howtofigureoutasentence.pdf). In this case the clauses are, logically:

- `SEE` (*I*, `LEAVE` (*she, room*))
- `HEAR` (*I*, `SHOUT` (*someone*))

In other words, the second clause is the direct object of the main clause that contains the sense verb -- they are [Object Complement clauses](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/complmnt.html).

Sense verbs are unusual, and have a number of syntactic peculiarities with their complement clauses:

- they can take all four kinds of complement clause
  (*that*-clause, embedded *wh*-question, gerund, infinitive)
- their infinitive complements mostly lack the *to* infinitive complementizer
- subjects of untensed (gerund, infinitive) complement clauses may or may not be present
- untensed complement subjects of sense verbs may undergo [B-Equi, or B-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), or neither

So, the middle two sentences are simple complement clauses, enhanced by being complements of sense verbs, which have quasi-superpowers (only Operators like [Modals, Quantifiers, and Negatives](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf) have actual superpowers)

---

Of the other two sentences, one:

- *We knew him to be a spy*

is, once again, an object complement clause (*be a spy* is a predicate noun -- `SPY` (*he*))

- `KNOW` (*we*, `SPY` (*he*))

*Know* can take a *that*-complement (with optional *that*, as usual):

- *We knew (that) he was a spy*

or an infinitive complement with B-Raising, and a normal *to* complementizer this time:

- *We knew him to be a spy*

There's little perceptible meaning in this distinction; only different syntax. The Raised subject in an infinitive clause can be passivized, for instance, but the subject in a *that*-clause can't:

- *He was known to be a spy*
- **He was known (that) was a spy.*

---

And the final sentence:

- *I got the watch repaired*

is an idiomatic construction with *get* ([one of many such constructions](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104219/15299); *get* has a number of meanings and uses in Modern English).

This is a causative *get* + `Past Participle` construction. There are two clauses, but their relationship is not obvious. The logical structure is something like:

- `CAUSE` (*I*, `COME ABOUT` (*repair* (`indef`, *watch*)))

or, in English:

- *I brought it about* (i.e, *I caused it to come about*) *that `Indef` repaired the watch*

That's rather a mouthful, and that's where *get* constructions come in.  One of *get's* meanings is the **inchoative** 'come to be' (*get tired, get sick, get lost, get fixed*),  and, like most English inchoatives, it can also be used as a **causative** 'cause `X` to come to be'  (*get him tired, get yourself sick, get her lost, get it fixed*). And that's what this one is.

Comment: Very clear and thorough.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the "Equi/Raising" link. It's 17 pages long, and consists of a number of handouts on the topics from various classes, with diagrams, and two sets of syntax lab problems, with answers.

Comment: Great as always!

Comment: @JohnLawler Im sorry to comment on something so old, but I have a question: I thought object complements always gain their definition by the fact that they describe the direct object, not that they are the direct object. For example, "I saw him running to the store." "Running to the store" is the object complement. However, your link documents seem to allude to the fact that "object complements" can best be described as complements that are objects. Is that true, and if so, do you consider the whole clause "him running to the store" as the object complement?

Comment: In general, English clauses have subjects. They may have objects, if they're transitive. Like the subject _you_ of imperatives, the subject of an untensed  subordinate clause (like an infinitive, gerund, or participle clause) is often missing, either indefinite, like _It's time (for someone) to fix supper_, or identical to another noun, like _I enjoy (me/my) having beer with supper_. Subject noun phrases of infinitives can appear after _for_, and of gerunds can be either possessive or objective in form; or they can be deleted, under specific conditions.

Comment: So, to answer the actual question "object clause" means "clause that is the object". And whole clauses can be objects, like _that_-clauses.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think I understand. So, object complements, in your definition, are the full object clauses, "him running to the store," not just the complements that describe the object?

Comment: In this case, yes. Not necessarily with every verb.