# I could hear something rattling/rattle

Tags: could

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Huddleston and Pullum) says under the section "**Past time *could***" at page 197 that it is possible to say

> (1) *I could hear something rattling.* [actualised ability (says CGEL)]

but not possible to say

> (2) * *I could hear something rattle.*

because *rattle* would be "perfective", says CGEL.

CGEL specifically says that "*could* does not normally appear in affirmative contexts when it is a matter of actualisation of a single situation viewed perfectively."

CGEL has another set of examples on this issue:

> (3) *Last night I **heard** the clock strike two.* (marked grammatical in CGEL)
>
> (4) * *Last night I **could hear** the clock strike two.* (marked ungrammatical in CGEL)

Now, here's a [conversation from an American movie "Real Steel" (2011)](http://www.moviequotesandmore.com/real-steel-quotes-1.html):

> Max Kenton: Charlie, I need you to teach him to box.
>
> Charlie Kenton: Are you kiddin' me? He's no where near advanced enough to handle Noisey's voice command.
>
> Max Kenton: Yeah, so we need you moves, your commands. Start over.
>
> Charlie Kenton: Forget it, kid.
>
> Max Kenton: From the ground up.
>
> Charlie Kenton: Forget it.
>
> Max Kenton: You were a boxer Charlie.
>
> Charlie Kenton: Yep.
>
> **Max Kenton:** *Yesterday at The Zoo, you **could** see things **happen** before they even happened.*
>
> Charlie Kenton: I haven't boxed in a long time, I'm not starting now.
>
> Max Kenton: You can teach him to fight.
>
> Charlie Kenton: You're doin' fine, Max. You don't need me, sorry.

How come it's not "you could see things **happening**" in the movie?

Is it some sort of BrE/AmE thing? Or is the movie script just being sloppy in its grammar?

Comment: [Sense verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299), unsurprisingly, have rather special grammar. One way it's special is that sense verbs can take [either a gerund or an infinitive complement clause.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/114389/15299) Ergo, both variants are correct, and there is no real difference; you pays your attention and you takes your choice. I have no idea why Huddleston or Pullum would say that; it's clearly incorrect.

Comment: You can just as easily hear things rattle as see them fly or smell them rot or feel them shake. Either CGEL is wrong or you have misunderstood them, or both.

Comment: @John Lawler, tchrist: Maybe someone having access to CGEL should be able to let us know if indeed it's an error on the book's part or on my part or something else.

Comment: @tchrist: Also, I'd like to mention that the focus is not on "can" but on "could". You might agree that you cannot say "*I left early but could get a seat," as shown ungrammatical in CGEL.

Comment: Let me ask John Lawler and tchrist and any native speaker of English for that matter: Do you find sentences (2) and (4) grammatical?

Comment: @JK2. You have correctly represented what the CGEL says. I am a native speaker and regard sentences such as _I left early and could get a good seat_ (CGEL) and _I ran after the bus and could catch it_ (A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, Quirk, p232) as ungrammatical. But I have no problem with past tense _could_ when the verb following _could_ is a sense verb: _I could hear something rattle_, or _You could see things happen before they even happened_. In fact, perfective (_rattle_) implies a short burst of sound as against a more prolonged sound in the imperfect (_rattling_).

Comment: I agree with Shoe's judgements. Conjunction Reduction of the subject doesn't work right in **I left early and could get a good seat*. It should be _I left early and I could get a good seat_, so the constraint there is on Conjunction Reduction; probly something about matching up auxiliaries, or else just more modal speciality. (2) and (4) I find grammatical; as I said, either a gerund or an infinitive.

Comment: "Is it some sort of BrE/AmE thing?". No,it is not.

Comment: I heard something rattle. one time. I heard something rattling. ongoing. No, 2) and 4) are grammatical.

Comment: I think it's far more likely that Huddleston and Pullum are simply wrong. (And I believe they are in this case.) The fact that they are authors of a published book doesn't make them infallible. I find nothing ungrammatical about the sentences marked as such.

Comment: Citing a movie is not best practice as actors and actresses manipulate the language in order to match the character they are playing. Meaning the language may or may not be standard.

Answer (score 6):

Certainly (4) is grammatical, and can be proved by a counterexample:

> Last night I could hear the clock [on the town hall] strike two, but by three the wind was in the wrong direction.

That is, the clock did strike two, and it was possible for me to hear that. It is an affirmative context of a matter of actualisation of a single situation viewed perfectively. CGEL is wrong to proscribe it, although its alternative *was able to* (also mentioned on p197) can be applied successfully.

That is sufficient to cast doubt on sentence (2), and while "I could hear something rattling" is probably more likely to be said, "I could hear something rattle" is not unidiomatic. Shoe's [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216804/i-could-hear-something-rattling-rattle#comment461800_216804) "In fact, perfective (rattle) implies a short burst of sound as against a more prolonged sound in the imperfect (rattling)" is apposite.

The problem with prescriptive grammar is that it cannot cover all possibilities, and dogmatic assertions such as the one you ask about may well not be right all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Thing is, CGEL claims to represent descriptive grammar as opposed to prescriptive grammar. I just can't believe they dropped the ball with not just one but two sentences on this issue. (Not that I don't believe you and others here!)

Comment: Say, you're riding a friend's car and you hear something rattling on that car. Would you ever say, "I can hear something rattle" instead of "I can hear something rattling"?

Comment: If I could hear something rattling (continuous) then I'd use *rattling*. If I heard something rattle (instantaneous) then I'd use *rattle*.

Comment: In a context where the rattle is continuous, would it be incorrect to say "I can hear something rattle"? If so, by the same token, if I was talking about a past event where the rattle was continuous, would it be incorrect to say "I could hear something rattle"? Maybe this is why CGEL was saying about the latter being ungrammatical?

Comment: I don't think I can make myself any clearer about my usage. I'm afraid I can't comment on how CGEL came to their conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

1 Someone laughed  (a fact). I could hear it.
2 Someone was laughing. I could hear it.

You can connect hear and all verbs of perception with accusative + infinitive when you merely want to state the fact
and you can use accusative and participle when you want to stress the progress of the action.
Don't let you confuse by CGEL. Sometimes you find very subjective views
such as English has no dative because in English the dative has no ending. That is one view. The other view is it is irrelevant how you express the function of dative - by an ending, by a preposition or merely by the position before an accusative. The function of dative is always clear.

CGEL tolerate only their view. The other view is not even mentioned or considered as wrong.

Comment: It's bare infinitive, not "to-infinitive". You probably want to correct your misstatement. Also, please elaborate more on the issue, rather than merely allege that CGEL is "subjective" based on an issue (dative) totally unrelated to the current one.

Comment: Also, it's one thing to make a "subjective" claim about a grammar category (dative), and it's another to make a false claim that a sentence is ungrammatical when most native speakers would find it grammatical. So if the latter is indeed the case, I may have found a serious flaw in CGEL, which I'm afraid is very unlikely, given that the book's been out there more than a decade and is still fairly respected by many.

Comment: @JK2 - Thanks. I corrected to-infinitive to infinitive.