# Why is this sentence infelicitous?

Tags: present-tense

Consider the sentence:

> I saw her **cry**.

Why is it, then, that we can't say:

> I saw her **be** crying.

And instead say:

> I saw her crying.

?

**Why is the second sentence infelicitous?**

Comment: I saw her sad/ being sad; upset/ being upset; happy/being happy; angry/ being (or) getting angry. [What do these words: *sad*, *upset*, *happy*, and *angry*
 have in common?]

Comment: Perhaps this question would fit better on our sister site: http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are three sentences. Which one of the three does the title refer to?  That is, which one do you call infelicitous? And what are you saying about the other two, are they felicitous? Please be more specific.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I've edited the question.

Comment: It doesn't sound infelicitous; it sounds wrong. I can't think of any variety of English that allows that.

Comment: Sense verbs like _see_ can take [several different kinds of complement clause](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/114389/15299), including gerunds (e.g, _crying_) and infinitives without _to_ (e.g, _cry_). Sentence (2) is bad because _be crying_ is a progressive infinitive, and these are rare without _to_; there is a rule called _to be_-deletion that removes both _to_ and _be_, but not just one. If you tried a passive infinitive, the _be_ might do better: _I saw him be arrested_ is not too bad, and _I saw him being arrested_ is just fine.

Comment: @John Lawler Would you give the precise definition of 'gerund' as you use it? I'm using '_ing_-form nearer the verbal end of the noun-verb continuum' for say 'crying' in 'I saw her crying'; I've come across conflicting usages of 'gerund' but would match the term more closely with the POSS-ing usage 'I heard his crying'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That’s too long a phrase for convenient use. Whatever you call it, it’s a non-finite VP whose subject is indicated in a non-nominative way. For purposes of answering the question asked by the OP, one should probably find something that works to describe all of: *I’ve seen him eat chips, I  see him eating chips,  I see his eating chips bothers her.*

Comment: @Edwin: I did a post on [various uses of -_ing_ forms and their properties](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html) some time ago. These days the only thing I'd add would be the `ACC`-_ing_ gerund complementizer as well as  `POSS`-_ing_. Otherwise it corresponds to the way I use the term. It's the verby end of the noun-verb cline, all right. Direct objects, no articles, adverbs, subjects either present or indefinite or governed by Equi, complement clauses used as subject or object. The gerund clause is an NP, but the gerund itself heads a VP.