# "Having you feel that way makes me feel hopeless" or Having you feeling that way makes me feel hopeless"?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis, gerund-vs-infinitive, causative-verbs, predicate-frames

Which sentence is grammatically correct and WHY?

Comment: That answer is not a duplicate; _have_ is not really a [sense verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/114389/15299). This is a different construction, but it still allows either a gerund or a _to_-less infinitive, both idiomatic.