# Three Consecutive Verbs?

Tags: grammar, verbs, adverbs

Let's say you're in an interview and the interviewer leans forward and says:

"I want to get to know you better."

In this context, which is the verb? My initial reaction is:
Want  - auxiliary verb
To get - main verb
To know - modal verb

Comment: In English, which is an **analytical** language, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_language) we  express verbal aspect lexically. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect

Comment: Could we calm down?  Maybe give Dave G some help improving his question?  For example, rather than simply demand research in a canned way, we could ask him: "where did you get this sentence?"

Comment: Reworded my question (-:

Comment: Here's a fun toy you can use to diagram this sentence: http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A sentence requires a subject and a predicate. A predicate is a verb plus whatever other elements make up a verb phrase. In this case, the subject, clearly, is *I*, while the predicate is the verb describing the state or action of the subject. In this case, that is *want*, in a transitive capacity. Everything after that is the direct object of *want*, a noun in effect, which can be replaced by a pronoun. In other words, this sentence can be reduced to *I want it.* The verb phrase itself contains two additional verb phrases, but the verb that is serving the subject is *want*.

Answer (score 4):

> *I **want** to **get** to **know** you better.*

There are three non-auxiliary **verbs**, [so there are three clauses](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/howtofigureoutasentence.pdf).

1. *want* is the present tense verb of the main clause
2. *get* is the untensed verb of the [infinitive complement clause](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/114389/15299) that's the object of *want*
3. *know* is the untensed verb of the infinitive complement clause that's the object of *get*.

As for the rest,

- *I* is the subject of the main clause
- *you* is the object of *know*
- *better* is an adverb modifying one of the clauses
- both occurrences of *to* are complementizers that introduce the infinitive verb phrases.

EDIT: All clauses have predicates, and in these clauses the verbs are the predicates.

*Predicate* is a logical term; logically, the predication structure of the sentence above
(without "*better*", which is semantically complex, ambiguous, and irrelevant) looks like this:

- *`Want`* (*`I`*, *`Get`* (*`I`*, *`Know`* (*`I`*, *`You`*)))
  (*Get* is used here in its idiomatic sense of 'come to be; become')

Comment: +1 I think the OP might be wondering what the Predicator is?

Comment: Sorry; shoulda been just _Predicate_.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no auxiliary or modal verb; they are all lexical verbs. "Want" is the main clause verb. The other two verbs, "get" and "know", head subordinate non-finite clauses embedded within the main clause.

*I want* **[** to get [*to know you better*]**]**.

I would treat your example as a catenative construction. The term ‘catenative’ is derived from the Latin word for chain, for the construction is repeatable in a way that enables us to form a chain of verbs in which all except the last have a non-finite complement:

Your example then comprises a main clause (the whole sentence) which contains two subordinate non-finite clauses (bracketed) functioning as catenative complements:

1. *to get* *to know you better* = catenative complement of “want”.
2. *to know you better* =  catenative complement of “get”.

The only direct object is “you” - it's the object of “know”, and the adverb “better” is a degree adjunct modifying "know”.