# Are there any rules of English grammar that can describe this structure?

Tags: grammaticality, formality

My specific question is, why is not any auxiliary followed by ***coming***?

I've seen a lot of sentences as following one, but this time it made me wonder if there was any grammar behind that like **omission** or **participle clause**, or it was just an informal spoken English.

> You feel another one coming?

I thought it could stand for *'Do you feel that another one is coming'* or *'... that another one comes'* or *'... that another one is going to come'* or *'... that another one will come'*.

In this sentence *one* refers to a bird, but I don't think this makes any difference.

Here is another example:

> Doctor to a pregnant woman: *"(Do) You feel another one coming?"* (one refers to contraction)

How about this example:

> (Do) You think he (or him) coming?

Comment: I believe some upvoted my question because they thought it was about *conversational deletion*, but it is not. So please, before any upvoting, read the questions thoroughly (or answer for that matter). P.S. Because of this reason, I needed to EDIT the question.

Answer (score 1):

There's two parts to this.

First, the omission of the auxiliary "Do". This is common in everyday speech for an immediate question. The auxiliary doesn't have to be 'do':

> You feel it? [Do]
>
> They coming? [Are]
>
> Seen it? [Have you]

The second question is about the participle "coming". I think you may be misparsing. This doesn't stand for "You feel that another one is coming?" - that would be perfectly grammatical, but has a slightly different meaning.

This is more like "You feel another one that is coming?". "Another one coming" is a noun phrase, the object of "feel". "Feel" in this case means "sense" or "be aware of", rather than "believe", or "expect".

Comment: This is an example of [Conversational Deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/15299), which is very common in speech. Basic rule: any sequence of predictable function words at the beginning of the sentence may be deleted.

Comment: I found another example using exactly *feel*. Doctor to a pregnant woman: "(Do) You feel another one coming?" (one refers to contractions). And I cannot understand if it is actually *Do you feel another one that is coming?* Would you mind explaining? By the way, I added another example into my question, if it makes any deference.

Comment: No, "You think he coming" is ungrammatical. "You hear him coming?" is fine. It's an object noun phrase, so it has to be 'him', not 'he'; and 'think' doesn't take a direct object like that (the only direct object it can take is a thought'. But verbs of perception - 'see', 'hear', 'feel' - do take a direct object of what is perceived. This emphasises how it is a completely different construction from "You think he is coming?" where the 'is' cannot be deleted.

Comment: @JohnLawler Honestly, my question wasn't about the conversational deletion.

Comment: The _feel/sense/see/hear `X` `V`-ing_ [sense verb construction](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/105101/15299) is common, and alternates with the _feel/sense/see/hear `X` `V`_ infinitive construction (without _to_). The gerund version is for events that are ongoing, while the infinitive is for reports of events: _She saw him speaking_ and _She saw him speak_. [There's not a great deal of difference](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/114389/15299).

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for the link. It was very helpful. I have to say again more than helpful. Wow!

Comment: @JohnLawler & Colin Fine Just one thing. In my example (i.e. *Do you feel another one coming?*) what happens to coming, Is that a matter of grammar that is applied to **participle clauses** or **sense verbs**?

Comment: _Coming_ is part of the structure. That's what happens to it. I guess I don't understand the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Afsane; like John Lawler, I don't understand you further questions.

Comment: The elided words are more like 'to be' than 'that be'.  'That' is restrictive.  It's easier to see if the object is definite, such as "Do you hear Bob coming?"