# participles as object complements

Tags: participles, present-participles, complements

Can participles or participial phrases serve as object complements in traditional grammar? And are direct objects viewed as a type of complement in traditional grammar?

I'd appreciate reference to standard works.

Comment: Is the CGEL treatment sufficiently well established to be considered 'traditional' yet? / Your second question [has been at least looked at here already](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114365/non-finite-clause-complementation-of-complex-transitive-verbs/114389#1143890).

Answer (score 0):

Paraphrasing  EnglishSentences.com A participial phrase is one that looks like a verb, but actually functions as an adjective; it modifies a noun in the same sentence. Phrases like this provide added description about what it’s doing or what it looks like.

If by object complements  you mean that which modifies a noun then the answer is yes. 
As for direct objects being viewed as a type of complement you should provide an example.

Comment: In "John likes apples," is "apples" a complement in traditional grammar?