# Bare infinitive or present participle?

Tags: gerunds, participles, present-participles, bare-infinitive

Which of the following two sentences is correct? The one that uses the bare infinitive 'hear', or the one that uses the present participle 'hearing'?

> He heard him snore last night.

Or

> He heard him snoring last night.

Comment: Hearing or snoring?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-finite clause complementation of complex transitive verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114365/non-finite-clause-complementation-of-complex-transitive-verbs)

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/hear?q=hear)) **hear somebody/something doing something**
> ♦ He could hear a dog barking.
> **hear somebody/something do something**
> ♦ Did you hear him go out?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of ***hear + snore/snoring***, the choice of verb form for the second element can't make any difference to the meaning, and [both are in common use...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heard+him+snore%2Cheard+him+snoring&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cheard%20him%20snore%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheard%20him%20snoring%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

BUT - there *could* be a difference between...

> 1: *I saw him hit her*
> 2: *I saw him hitting her*

...where #1 implies he hit her *once*, and #2 implies he hit her *repeatedly*. Note that although it's relatively unlikely, it's at least *possible* to use either of those two forms where the specified implication *doesn't* apply.